# Props in class variable is undefined

Tags: react-native

I am trying to learn some react native, but I am struggling with a problem related to class variables. This is my code (I didn't paste the whole one because it's very long, but this should give an idea of my issue):

```
class VideoScreen extends Component {
static _toHHMMSS(time) {
    var sec_num = parseInt(time, 10); // don't forget the second param
    var hours = Math.floor(sec_num / 3600);
    var minutes = Math.floor((sec_num - (hours * 3600)) / 60);
    var seconds = sec_num - (hours * 3600) - (minutes * 60);

    if (hours < 10) {
        hours = "0" + hours;
    }
    if (minutes < 10) {
        minutes = "0" + minutes;
    }
    if (seconds < 10) {
        seconds = "0" + seconds;
    }
    return hours + ':' + minutes + ':' + seconds;
}

_currentTime = <View refreshing>
    <Text>{VideoScreen._toHHMMSS(this.props.currentTime)}
    </Text>
</View>;

render() {
    return (
        <View refreshing>
            {this._currentTime}
        </View>
    )
}
```

}

unfortunately props is undefined inside the variable "_currentTime". If I move the view directly into the render method it works fine (I need it in a separate variable because I will need to hide it according to a boolean value and creating the variable makes the code much more readable). Do I have to bind the variable to the class as you do with methods, or maybe am I doing something else wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that `this` is not bound. I'm not sure if you can bind a variable but you can achieve what you want with a method:

```
class VideoScreen extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
       super(props);
       this._currentTime = this._currentTime.bind(this);
    }

    render() {
        return (
           <View refreshing>
               {this._currentTime()}
           </View>
        )
    }

    _currentTime() {
       return (
           <View refreshing>
               <Text>{VideoScreen._toHHMMSS(this.props.currentTime)}
               </Text>
           </View>
       );
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Giorgos, thanks for your reply. This is what I thought as well, but unfortunately it is not possible to bind the variable, at least it's not possible using the bind() method as you suggested :-(

Comment: wait a sec, so you are suggesting to turn the variable into a function... I will try it and see it works. Thanks in the meantime!

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks! The only thing is that you need to execute the function by calling {this._currentTime()} inside the render method ;-)

Comment: Alright, I edited my answer to `{this._currentTime()}`. I think that if you use ES6 syntax like this: `{() => this._currentTime()}` then you don't even need to bind the function in the constructor.